# Background image is not showing in the header

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have quite a problem with CSS. This is my code:

```
header {
   background-color: #FFE0E0;
   background-image: url('obrazky\logo.gif');    
   background-position: top right;    
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

and the problem is that my background image is not showing in the header. I am 100% sure that url to my image is correct. Any ideas why it isn't showing up or how to fix it? I use Google Chrome.

Comment: Use forward slash instead of `\\`

Comment: where is stored the logo.if respect  the html page .?. show you files struct

Comment: need more info/code. It could be that you need to set height width.

Comment: To solve such problems, I suggest you to use Chrome Debugger or Firefox debugger, and navigate to the header element and check it. (for example right-click the url and open it in new tab and see where is the problem). I'm sure this will help you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a fixed height and width for the element. The background image itself does not occupy any space in the element. Such as:

```
width: 200px;
height: 500px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must setup the height of the header, eg:

```
height: 600px;
```

If you can see just the header with the background color and without the image, then the image path is wrong, I think it is the first time I've seen a backslash instead of a forward one in a bg url, so try:

```
background-image: url('obrazky/logo.gif')
```